# add tracking pixel to each image in jquery image carousel

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, tracking

i have an image carousel written in jquery. now i need to be able to track which of the individual images are shown and which are clicked. i got my click-count URL and my view count tag, but i'm unsure of how to do this.

1. How/where do i add the view count tag for the individual images? in the css as a background image? in the php/html code after the image?
2. how can i know which images have been shown to the user, considering that all the images a re loaded when the page loads, and the overflow is hidden? i was thinking of something like a callback fired by the move of the carousel, so it would reload the images that are currently visible?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Why even use a tracking image? Wouldn't an AJAX call suffice? Or you could load the tracking image to a hidden dummy image on carousel click. Without seeing your code it's hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to add more to the html? Your server can already handle this:

In the simplest case, just server your images as `/getandtrack.php?image=/images/etc.png` instead of `/images/etc.png`. Then `getandtrack.php` does the tracking, then redirects to the image that was requested.

```
<?php
$image = @$_GET['image'];
if($image) {
    doTracking($image);
    header('Location: ' . $image)
}
```